# Plotting maps dynamically based on the availability of geographical data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with House, Streetname, City, Post code, Country, Latitude and Longitudes. As the latitude and longitudes will not be available for all the addresses, I would like to implement a logic in tableau that will use the co-ordinates (if available in the data), otherwise, Tableau has to plot the maps based on country and post code.

The dashboard that I am using currently is plotting the maps based on Country and Post code only. Is there a possibility to implement the logic explained above, to make the dashboard even more better? Please help.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get map according to your requirement as citywise or zipcode wise etc

Follow the steps as under:

Step1:
[map according to city]
as https://i.stack.imgur.com/in38c.png

It will automatically change the map according to zip code etc